# implementing the switching to another socket channel in an angular app

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my DashBoard component, the Dash object containing all the information I need is supposed to come from the server via a socket channel.

These channels related to some options that user may choose on the dashboard. That's, if he selects one option I should connect him to one channel, if he selects another option, I connect him to another channel.

In order to connect to a certain channel I should first make a POST http request with some parameters needed to provide a request with expected data.

In response the server sends me the right channel name (actually it's a hash that should be appended at the end of the url I use to establish a socket connection). I put this hash in the local storage.

To subscribe to a channel I wrote a service that is used as follows:

```
this.socketInfoService.getDashInfoBySocket(channelName).subscribe(
  (res: Dash) => this.dash = res
)
```

Just to figure out how things work, I first decided to write a certain method on my Dash component that expects a socket channel as its argument and opens/subscribes to the channel.

That's, something like this (I know it's all bad but for the lack of knowledge and time I can't come up with anything better right now):

```
public changeChannel(newChannelName: string)
{
    if (this.sub) 
    {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.sub = this.socketInfoService.getDashInfoBySocket(newChannelName).subscribe(
        (res: Dash) => this.dash = res
    )
}
```

But the thing is that it does not work, it does the unsubscribing part but never subscribes to another channel for some reason. I can't see why. How should I handle this issue?

I'm totally new to that stuff and I feel entirely lost, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if this is the exact same code, maybe because when you subscribe channelName is not a defined variable and should be newChannelName?

Comment: @BobBills Oops, no, it's okay in the code, I decided to change the variable name to a better one and forgot to change it in all places, sorry, that was my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating your component variables inside the Angular zone:

```
public changeChannel(newChannelName: string)
{
    if (this.sub) 
    {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.sub = this.socketInfoService.getDashInfoBySocket(channelName).subscribe(
        (res: Dash) => {
                   this.zone.run(() => {
                        this.dash = res; 
                   });
        }
    )
}
```

where `zone` is a service from `@angular/core`

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }
```

Comment: I've just tried but no, I did not work in my case. Perhaps it's worth mentioning, I fire the chaneChannel method in `ngOnInit` and it's also triggered on a click event in the template. It's just for the test and try purpose.